# how to check cpu utilization historically

Tags: rhel, cpu-usage

For the last 2 days I have a 30% higher cpu usage between 21:00 - 21:15 o'oclock on my redhat 8 server. I have an Oracle database on this server.
Is there anyway to check cpu utilization historically?
I tried to check `SAR` LOG files but I coundn't find so much details like process id or etc. in the log file.

```
    08:58:01 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
    08:59:00 PM     all      2.00      0.00      1.71     26.75      0.00     69.54
    09:00:00 PM     all      1.50      0.00      1.05     51.85      0.00     45.59
    09:01:00 PM     all      1.41      0.00      0.98     31.63      0.00     65.98
    09:02:02 PM     all      1.54      0.00      1.21     28.78      0.00     68.47
    09:03:06 PM     all      2.62      0.00      1.63     36.82      0.00     58.93
    09:04:00 PM     all      1.73      0.00      1.04     30.05      0.00     67.18
    09:05:01 PM     all      1.39      0.00      0.94     40.89      0.00     56.78
    09:06:11 PM     all      2.10      0.00      1.11     21.01      0.00     75.78
    09:07:05 PM     all      1.60      0.00      1.33     20.29      0.00     76.78
    09:08:07 PM     all      1.64      0.00      1.26     14.76      0.00     82.34
    09:09:12 PM     all      1.43      0.00      1.19     25.81      0.00     71.58
    09:10:01 PM     all      1.44      0.00      1.26     13.56      0.00     83.73
    09:11:12 PM     all      1.30      0.00      1.17     23.38      0.00     74.15
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If sar is installed and running you already have the historical data for one month in /var/log/sa directory. you can use them with `sar -f /var/log/sa/saXX`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dnf install atop
```

will get it covered but there are many other tools for that:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:System_monitors

The most famous/popular as of today are perhaps Grafana, Prometheus and Zabbix.